# Wacky voltage issues

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

Tested all the breakers and wires outside got normal voltage. Turned on one breaker read voltage again normal, turn on another makes voltage on other breaker too high. So turned second one off and normal voltage outside but inside is like 9 volts. Changed all the breakers even the main breaker and all the outlets. Added better grounding and still can only use one light and nothing else.

Comment: Have you checked to see if the neutral is open or not solidly connected_ Floating voltages may mean feedback between circuits because there is no direct path to neutral.

Comment: Your power company will come and check their wires to the the meter for free.  A loss neutral is not safe.

Comment: This is classic **lost neutral** behavior. Call the power company ASAP.

Comment: Apart from the linked duplicate, which was most similar to yours, you can search for "lost neutral" and sort by score if you want more reading on the subject.